# Как ускорить ViewPageIndicator?

Tags: java, android, viewpageindicator

Всем добрый день!
В процессе разработки приложения появилась необходимость использования библиотеки `ViewPageIndicator`.
Интегрировал данную библиотеку в свое приложение и все работает корректно, но жутко раздражает проблема с пролистыванием `ViewPager`, он работает как резина, то есть жест пролистывания довольно длинный и поэтому он срабатывает как резинка.
Как изменить реагирование `ViewPager` на жест таким образом, чтобы он пролистывался так же как `PageConroller` на `iOS`, то есть маленьким плавным движением пальца!

Извините если данный вопрос кажется бредовым! Ночь не спал поэтому даже нормально не могу сформулировать мысль!

Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: Отлично -1! А за что?

Comment: за то, что кто-то считает этот вопрос глупым, тем не менее не зная ответа. Восстановлю справедливость, ибо самому не помешает узнать ответ.

Comment: То что сейчас накопал по данному вопросу, это то что в android support library v 4 у ViewPager есть константы которые все портят.

private static final int MAX_SETTLE_DURATION = 1600; // ms
private static final int MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_FLING = 25; // dips